# How to resize a user control with subcontrols (pictureboxes)

Tags: c#, controls

I have a user control (100x800).
On this user control are 4 pictureboxes (1-4) - each 100x200.
The pictureboxes fill the complete control like this:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

My question:
If the control is resized, I want that the pictureboxes still fill the whole user control.
Can I achieve this by setting anchor, docking style or other properties or can this only be achieved by doing complex calculations in a resize event?

The best I could get until now is that the pictureboxes keep the same width as the user control, but then the height of the boxes get very low so that the boxes are only thin stripes and do not cover the whole control.

Comment: Are you merely placing the PictureBox components on the control using the designer?

Comment: Yes. But I can do it in another way if needed.

Comment: Could you provide an illustration as to what your desired effect is please?

Comment: <IMG>http://i42.tinypic.com/6e0rnl.png

Comment: See my answer, I'm not sure if it's what you want though so let me knwo.

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel to get automatic layout like this.

Comment: Thanks. Works great with TableLayoutPanel! All the picture boxes have to be set with 0 margins, and rows have to be set with percentage size.